# Trying to understand operator precedence with assign by reference

Tags: php, reference, variable-assignment

[Operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) tells that order should be: `+, &, =`. But this code execution shows that order is: `&, =, +`

```
$b = 1;
$a = & $b + print('print executed');
if ($a == 1)
    echo ' but one was not added and error was not raised';
```

Output `print executed but one was not added and error was not raised`

Why precedence is changed for this case?

P.S.

```
$a = new stdClass();

$c = &$a instanceof $a;
var_dump($c); // class stdClass#1 (0) {}

$b = $a instanceof $a;
var_dump($b); // bool(true)
```

Comment: Oh sectus, why do you make my eyes hurt so much?

Comment: @Ja͢ck, I am just curious...

Comment: The `&` is not the binary 'and' operator here.

Comment: @Ja͢ck, I know it. But they related. Bitwise & and reference & has one place in precedence table. But in this case it's a reference.

Comment: What exactly would the expected result be here?! You want to assign the value of `$b + (1)` *by reference*? Since that doesn't make any sense, the result here is somewhere between undefined and expected as is.

Comment: Personally I would say that this should be disallowed; the fact that no errors are raised is just a coincidence, because any other combinations of `+` and `&$b` *do* raise an error, e.g. `123 + &$b` or `(&$b) + 123`.

Comment: @deceze, I am expecting execution with order that documented. But it seems that combination of `=` and `&` has higher precedence than arithmetic operations.

Comment: And what exactly would you expect the result to look like if it did execute in the right order? In other words, why is the result you're getting an indication of the wrong order of execution and what would indicate a "correct" execution instead?

Comment: @deceze, other example added. I think that correct execution should raise an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably, this doesn't really answer your question but consider this code:

```
$b = 1;
$a = &$b + 123;
```

The opcodes reveal the following execution strategy:

```
compiled vars:  !0 = $b, !1 = $a
line     # *  op                       fetch          ext  return  operands
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   ASSIGN                                              !0, 1
   4     1      ASSIGN_REF                                   $1      !1, !0
         2      ADD                                          ~2      $1, 123
         3      FREE                                                 ~2
```

As you can see, the assignment by reference takes place and the addition gets stored in a temporary variable and then freed; basically, a no-op.

Perhaps the documentation could be clearer, but I can't imagine a scenario in which this particular code would ever make sense :)

Comment: Yes. My thoughts was correct precedence. And there is one operator(`= &` ASSIGN_REF) instead of two. It's flaw of the documentation.